# How to adjust the length of a photon line in latex?

Tags: tikz-feynman

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\title{A Quick Introduction to Quantum field theory}
\begin{document}\date{}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=p2 to p3] { p2 -- [photon] p3 }; 
\end{document}
```

I use this code to draw a photon line in Overleaf. I just wanted to reduce the length of the photon line to between 1 and 2 cm, for that how I modify the code?

Comment: Please make your code snippet a complete and compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. This helps others to help you.

Comment: I edited the question@muzimuzhi Z

Comment: Have you tried `\feynmandiagram[small, horizontal=p2 to p3]`? Use LuaLaTeX compiler in Overleaf.